# Find world space coordinate for pixel in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, 2d

I need to find the world coordinate of a pixel using OpenCV. So when I take pixel (0,0) in my image (that's the upper-left corner), I want to know to what 3D world space coordinate this pixel corresponds to on my image plane. I know that a single pixel corresponds to a line of 3D points in world space, but I want specific the one that lies on the image plane itself.

This is the formula of the OpenCV Pinhole model of which I have the first (intrinsics) and second (extrinsics) matrices. I know that I have u and v, but I don't know how to get from this u and v to the correct X, Y and Z coordinate.

[image: Pinhole Model Opencv]

What I've tried already:

- I thought to just set s to 1 and make a homogeneous coordinate from [u v 1]^T by adding a 1, like so: [u v 1 1]^T. Then I multiplied the intrinsics with the extrinsics and made it into a 4x4 matrix by adding the following row: [0 0 0 1]. This was then inverted and multiplied with [u v 1 1]^T to get my X, Y and Z. But when I checked if four pixels calculated like that lay on the same plane (the image plane), this was wrong.

So, any ideas?

Comment: What do you call the 'image plane' ?

Comment: if you compute the inverse of the intrinsics, you can multiply it to the left of both sides. then you have to revert the extrinsics (is there a `left-inverse`?). At the end you should have some formula giving you the pixel-to-world coordinates depending on your choice of `s`. If you create a formula that describes your 3D-world-plane, you can compute the single `s` that hits the plane.

Comment: adding another [1] as you've done might work too, just keep the `s` ... I guess it should be `[s*u,s*v,s,1]` but I'm not sure ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC you want the intersection I with the image plane of the ray that back-projects a given pixel P from the camera center.

Let's define the coordinate systems first. The usual OpenCV convention is as follows:

- Image coordinates: origin at the top-left corner, u axis going right (increasing column) and v axis going down.
- Camera coordinates: origin at the camera center C, z axis going toward the scene, x axis going right and y axis going downward.

Then the image plane in camera frame is z=*fx*, where fx is the focal length measured in pixels, and a pixel (u, v) has camera coordinates (u - *cx*, v - *cy*, *fx*).

Multiply them by the inverse of the (intrinsic) camera matrix K you'll get the same point in metrical camera coordinates.

Finally, multiply that by the inverse of the world-to-camera coordinate transform [R | t] and you'll get the same point in world coordinates.

Comment: Why do you use fx and not fy?

Comment: how could you be sure that [R|T] is invertible in this case?