# How to find correspondence of 3d points and 2d points

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a set of 3d points in world coordinates and respective correspondences with 2d points in an image. I want to find a matrix that gives me the transformation between these set of points. How can I do this in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2):

[`cv::solvePnP()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) is what you are looking for, it finds an object pose from 3D-2D point correspondences and results a rotation vector (`rvec`), that, together with translation vector (`tvec`), brings points from the model coordinate system to the camera coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you! But how would I invert that transformation? i.e. how would I project an image point to the 3d world? (Assuming some fixed z coordinate)

Comment: but how would I then project that image onto the 3d space or vice versa?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011873/find-world-space-coordinate-for-pixel-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

you can use [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnp) for this:

```
    // camMatrix based on img size
    int max_d = std::max(img.rows,img.cols);
    Mat camMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
        max_d,   0, img.cols/2.0,
        0,   max_d, img.rows/2.0,
        0,   0,     1.0);

    // 2d -> 3d correspondence
    vector<Point2d> pts2d = ...
    vector<Point3d> pts3d = ...
    Mat rvec,tvec;
    solvePnP(pts3d, pts2d, camMatrix, Mat(1,4,CV_64F,0.0), rvec, tvec, false, SOLVEPNP_EPNP);
    // get 3d rot mat
    Mat rotM(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Rodrigues(rvec, rotM);

    // push tvec to transposed Mat
    Mat rotMT = rotM.t();
    rotMT.push_back(tvec.reshape(1, 1));

    // transpose back, and multiply
    return camMatrix * rotMT.t();
```

Comment: How can I then project my image onto that 3d space?